# Extract the desired value with formula function or vba function

Tags: excel, vba, function

How to extract the desired value with formula function or vba function.

The sample table data is below I want to retrieve the desired value as the result below. Please have a solution.

Thanks

| ITEM | DESIRED RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| MATERIAL BALLOTELY CREM | CREM |
| MATERIAL KATUN ABU (76) | ABU |
| MATERIAL Katun Ima GOLD | GOLD |
| MATERIAL BALLOTELY HIJAU | HIJAU |
| MMATERIAL KATUN NAVY (04) | NAVY |
| MATERIAL KATUN IMA TURQIS | TURQIS |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO PINK (09) | PINK |
| MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08 | PB 08 |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO HIJAU (63) | HIJAU |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU PUTIH | PUTIH |
| MATERIAL KATUN WALLY CREAP HIJAU MINT (04) | HIJAU MINT |
| MATERIAL KATUN T. ASIN (18) | T. ASIN |
| MATERIAL CORDOBA FANTA (04) | FANTA |
| MATERIAL Katun Ima Ungu Tua | Ungu Tua |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO KUBUS (10A) | KUBUS |
| MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08 ( A ) | PB 08 |
| MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08 ( B ) | PB 08 |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU ABU SMA (02) | ABU SMA |
| MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU GOLD (23) | GOLD |
| MATERIAL IMA PLATINUM FANTA (10 A) | FANTA |
| MATERIAL IMA PLATINUM PINK SEDANG (16) | PINK SEDANG |
| MATERIAL BALOTELLI T. ASIN (31) | T. ASIN |

Comment: I guess you could use a dictionary? Or a Vlookup? lots of possibilities. Which one are you using?

Comment: ^^ In order to know the difference between outputs like 'MINT' or 'HIJAU MINT' you'd need a lookup database of some sort. Excel is not smart enough on it's own to figure this out for you.

Comment: @braX , if using a dictionary please give an example and if using vlookup please give an example

Comment: You are having trouble finding examples of those things?

Comment: @braX , yes right I had a hard time finding a solution to the example I posted

Comment: @JvdV , please you can guide me what to do

Comment: Can't be done since you have a random number of words in the materials and in the desired results. If you can write all the possible materials (the left repeating part) in a column, it would become doable. Also, determine how to handle the contents in parentheses and any other surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways of doing this. If the sample table is the limit of the input options, then the simplest way would be to use a Case Statement:

```
Function getcode(t as string)
    Select Case t
        Case "MATERIAL BALLOTELY CREM": code = "CREM"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN ABU (76)": code = "ABU"
        Case "MATERIAL Katun Ima GOLD": code = "GOLD"
        Case "MATERIAL BALLOTELY HIJAU": code = "HIJAU"
        Case "MMATERIAL KATUN NAVY (04)": code = "NAVY"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN IMA TURQIS": code = "TURQIS"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO PINK (09)": code = "PINK"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08": code = "PB 08"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO HIJAU (63)": code = "HIJAU"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU PUTIH": code = "PUTIH"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN WALLY CREAP HIJAU MINT (04)": code = "HIJAU MINT"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN T. ASIN (18)": code = "T. ASIN"
        Case "MATERIAL CORDOBA FANTA (04)": code = "FANTA"
        Case "MATERIAL Katun Ima Ungu Tua": code = "Ungu Tua"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO KUBUS (10A)": code = "KUBUS"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08 ( A )": code = "PB 08"
        Case "MATERIAL KATUN IMA PB 08 ( B )": code = "PB 08"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU ABU SMA (02)": code = "ABU SMA"
        Case "MATERIAL TOYOBO FODU GOLD (23)": code = "GOLD"
        Case "MATERIAL IMA PLATINUM FANTA (10 A)": code = "FANTA"
        Case "MATERIAL IMA PLATINUM PINK SEDANG (16)": code = "PINK SEDANG"
        Case "MATERIAL BALOTELLI T. ASIN (31)": code = "T. ASIN"
        Case Else: code = "Code not found"
    End Select
    getcode = code
End Function
```

However, another method is to remove the words that are not wanted and just leave behind the desired code. Easier to maintain if the list is going to grow:

```
Function getcode(t As String)
    arrReplace = Array("MATERIAL", "BALLOTELY", "KATUN", "IMA", "TOYOBO", "WALLY", "CREAP", "FODU", "CORDOBA", "PLATINUM", "BALOTELLI")
    For Each strReplace In arrReplace
        t = Replace(t, strReplace & " ", "", , , vbTextCompare)
    Next
    t = Split(t, "(")(0)
    getcode = Trim(t)
End Function
```